# Does there exist a bijective map between a matrix and a scalar with entries from a finite field or finite ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, linear-transformations

I have a $2\times2$ matrix with entries from GF($2^8$) say:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$

Is this possible to map $A$ to a scalar $k$ and then in reverse find the matrix $A$ from the scalar $k$ (from field or ring). One may consider $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ from a finite field or from any other finite algebraic structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you requiring the bijection to be linear? Or can it be any bijection?

Comment: bijection to a linear.

Comment: If the entries are integers, you can map that matrix to $e=2^a3^b5^c7^d$, and from $e$ you can recover $A$. If the entries come from a field of $q$ elements ($q$ finite), you can first map the elements of the field any way you like to the integers $1,2,\dots,q$, thus reducing it to a problem already solved.

Comment: For an infinite set $A$, there exists a bijection $A \leftrightarrow A^4$ (and the latter is naturally isomorphic to $M_2(A)$ even as an $A$-vector space), but the first set equivalence will not respect any of the algebraic structure that makes matrices interesting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson can you please elaborate it with an example for a finite field of q elements.

Comment: I believe there is a linear bijection between $M_2 (\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}})$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^{4n}}$ when viewed as vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Do the scalars have to come from the same algebraic structure?

Comment: @Chris, yes the scalars are from the same algebraic structure. you may consider them from GF(2^2).

Comment: OK, if $a,b,c,d$ are in the field $\{\,r,s\,\}$ of two elements, then you can map $r$ to $1$, and $s$ to $2$, and that tells you how to map each of $a,b,c,d$ to $1$ or $2$, and now you have a matrix with all entries $1$ or $2$, and you can map that to the appropriate number of the form $2^u3^v5^x7^y$, with $u,v,x,y$ taken from $\{\,1,2\,\}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I took a=b=c=d=1 and calculated $2^1$$3^1$$5^1$$7^1$ that results 2 in GF($2^3$). Now I am not able how to retrieve a,b,c,d.  Can you please guide me in the reverse process?

Comment: But I'm not in the field of eight elements, I'm defining a function whose codomain is the positive integers, so $2^13^15^17^1=210$, and you retrieve $a,b,c,d$ by factoring $210$. I think you have in mind a lot of properties you want your function to have, that you haven't stated in the question. It would be best if you would edit your question to state explicitly what properties you want your function to have.

Comment: just take any bijection from R^4 to R

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are all elements of $GF(2^8)$ then you can do the following. The field $GF(2^{32})$ is a 4-dimensional vector space over $GF(2^8)$. It has a vector space basis of the form $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ for some $\alpha\in GF(2^{32})$. Then you can map the matrix $A$ to the element
$$z=z(A)=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3\in GF(2^{32}).$$ Because we have a basis, knowing $z$ is equivalent to knowing $a,b,c,d$. But I really don't see the point of doing this Effectively I am just storing the matrix $A$ in an unnecessarily complicated way.

Comment: And this question has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:algebraic-geometry] or [tag:permutation-matrices], so I removed the tags. Please read the tag descriptions before using them if you are unfamiliar with their (often technical) meaning.